# How to get a stack trace from inside a template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

For reasons I won't get into, I can't use xdebug right now.

Is there a way to dump a stack trace from inside a Twig template running inside a Symfony 4 application without installing or creating any special Twig extensions?

This seems like it would be a common question, but Google was surprisingly unhelpful on a few related terms. I'm hoping there's an easy way.

====

Edit: Using the Symfony debug toolbar is also not an option at the moment.

Comment: Are you able to use the profile (web debug toolbar)?

Comment: Good suggestion. Sadly, in this case, I cannot.

Comment: Can you not use it because you are in production? I ask because if so, your stack trace probably won't show you much that is useful, just a lot of noise from the various includes in the twig system and compiled containers. Otherwise, to the best of my knowledge, this is only possible with an extension.

Comment: Good points. The environment is local/dev, but it's in the context of putting together an API endpoint, and the SF toolbar is disabled in our shared project because of some other dependencies that muck it up. There are no explicit calls to any Twig inclusions, but it is being included via ... magic! Always fun. Anyway, yes, I will probably write a simple extension for this and put it up on packagist if I don't hear any surprise answers from folks on how to do this. Thanks for having given me a sanity check to fall back on before I started writing the extension!

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a Twig extension for this.

https://packagist.org/packages/patrick-maynard/twig-stack-trace-dumper

I hope this helps somebody.